# Wrong prawn method or wrong object?

Tags: ruby, csv, prawn

I am trying to get  programm started where i cant read in a csv File an it prints the data out on a pdf-File. Now i have a problem.
Heres is my Code:

```
------------------------------------
require_relative 'friends'

class List

  attr_accessor :list_name, :list

  def initialize(list_name)
    @list_name = list_name
    @list = []
  end

  def list_name
    @list_name
  end

  def liste
    @list
  end

  def wert(place)
    @list[place].to_s
  end

  def list_length
    @list.length
  end

  def print_list
    @list.each do |freunde|
    "#{freunde.name},#{freunde.age}"
    end
  end

  def add_friend(a_friend)
    @list.push(a_friend)
  end

  def load_friend(from_file)
      File.readlines(from_file).each do |line|
        add_friend(Freunde.from_csv(line))
      end
  end

end
-------------------------------------------

  require_relative 'list'

  class Friends

    attr_accessor :name,:age

    def initialize(name, age)
      @name = name
      @age = age
    end

    def self.from_csv(string)
      name, age = string.split(',')
      Freunde.new(name,age)
    end

   def friends
    @name
   end
  end   
-------------------------------------------

require 'prawn'
require_relative 'list'
require_relative 'friends'


class Generating
include Prawn::View

  def initialize
    @document = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => "A4")
    @fontpath = File.expand_path("../data/fonts", __FILE__)
    liste1 = Listen.new("Friendslist")
    liste1.load_friend("test.csv")
    print_list
    save
  end

  def print_friends
    font("#{@fontpath}/Arial.ttf") do
        font_size 11
        text_box("#{liste1.print_list}", :at => [15,405], :height => 50, 
        :width => 250)
end
  end

  def save
    self.render_file "Hello.pdf"
  end
end
---------------------------------------------
```

When i now create a new generating-Object:

```
gen = Generating.new
```

then it fails the whole programm because the error says method unknow (print_list). Am i submitting the wrong object for the method(print_list), or am using the text output methods of prawn wrong?

Comment: "the error says method unknow (print_list)" – I *highly* doubt that that is what the error says. I am 100% certain that it will *at least* tell you a line number and show a stack trace. Without that, there is not enough information for us to help you. What is the *precise* error message? What result do you expect and why? What is the desired behavior and why? Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? …

Comment: … Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve]. (With a specific focus on *minimal*: I highly doubt it requires 100 lines to reproduce the problem, in fact, I bet, you can demonstrate the problem in 2 short lines.)

Comment: My Error says, "in my path where the Gem Prawn is installed:C:/Ruby24-64/....  in "method_missing": undefinde local variable or method "print_list" for #<Generating:0x2318460>".

Comment: And i thank you, but i think my question is enough information what i am worriyng about: Am i casting the method (.print_list) on the wrong method or am i using the wrong method for text in prawn. Because again someone solveld the problem and the programm runs but it didnt prints the text on the pdf_file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print_list` is an instance method of `List` class, and you call it on `self` object, which is there an instance of `Generating`. It should be:

```
liste1 = Listen.new("Friendslist")
liste1.load_friend("test.csv")
#⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
liste1.print_list
```

Comment: Thank you, now my Code runs, but it didnt prints out the Method lines in the pdf-File. There is no error Message, the pdf-File is rendered but blank.

Comment: If you have another problem, please post another question. The problem stated in this question is resolved, and the SO’s rule of thumb is “one question per one problem.”